# How to dismiss AlertDialog.Builder without onClick methods of buttons?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, illegalstateexception

I have these 2 methods to create and destroy AlertDialog which only has progress bar.

```
public static AlertDialog.Builder showProgressAlertDialog(Context context, String title){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
    builder.setView(progressBar);
    builder.show();
    return builder;
}

public static void dismissProgressAlertDialog(AlertDialog.Builder builder){
    builder.show().cancel();
}
```

There are no errors while creating it. However, when I call the dismiss method, application throws the following exception: *java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.*

Note that, I need to call this method and destroy the dialog from another class, therefore *onClick* method will not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dismiss() on the instance variable of AlertDialog

```
private AlertDialog dialog;

onCreate() {
    dialog = createAlertDialog(context, title);
}

public static AlertDialog createAlertDialog(Context context, String title){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
    builder.setView(progressBar);
    return builder.create();
}

public static void dismissAlertDialog() {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store instance of `AlertDialog` by a global `Field` in Class, Now you can access to `AlertDialog` object in all of the class

```
private AlertDialog alertDialog;

public void onCreate(){
  this.alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
.create();
}

public void show(){
 this.alertDialog.show()
}

public void close(){
 this.alertDialog.dismiss()
}
```